# Javascript - Photoshop Script - Extract all filled areas into new layer

Tags: javascript, photoshop

What command will select each section of one color in an image and promote it to a new layer. The magic wand would do the trick selecting each blob individually, but I want a script that will automate it.

For example, if there's twelve white squares in an image, I want twelve seperate layers extracted each having one of the white squares.

Comment: It is extendscript dude....

Comment: I use Javascript. I'm a web developer so its easier for me. You are correct tho, the program is called ExtendScript.

Comment: Photoshop is not very good at determining certain colours programmatically. You might try Colour Range with the script listener though. Or if you know the co-ordinates of where you want the magic wand to click you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the script that can help you is found [here](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/split-to-layers/). But it needs an transparent background and I don't know how well it executes on newer Photoshop versions. But I would give it a shot.